# How to add fonticon or glyph in xamarin.forms xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

In UWP XAML you can use TextBlock

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="40">&#xE114;</TextBlock>
```

or

FontIcon/Glyph

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Glyph="&#xE114;"/>
```

How does one do it in XAMARIN.FORMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may also use the same style in UWP XAML.

for example,you can add a label in the portable project

```
<Label Text="&#xE700;" 
       FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

In the uwp test ,the text icon is showing in the device.

Comment: You'd have to have the Segoe MDL2 Assets font on all the devices for it to work. I dont know how, but I'm pretty sure there's a way to include fonts in your Android/iOS builds.